# When add a column to a data.table, what's then best way to add if else conditions?

Tags: r, data.table

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
 dt[isFlag, newCol:= A]
 dt[!isFlag, newCol:=B]
```

Or should I do this?

```
 dt[, newCol:= B]
 dt[isFlag, newCol:=A]
```

Or this?

```
 dt[, newCol:= if (isFlag) then A else B] # this only works if isFlag is a scalar
```

Or

```
dt[, newCol:= ifelse(isFlag, A, B)] # this only works if isFlag is a vector
```

What is the best way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second also works for isFlag scalar...Did you try it out? Anyway, the second way (`ifelse`) is what you want to use to achieve the goal you stated at the top.

Comment: @Frank No, the second would fail if I do `ifelse(TRUE, c(1,2), c(3,4))` `isFlag` cannot be recycled.

Comment: Good to know; I didn't realize it worked that way. Anyway, it "works" insomuch as it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: I'd go with option two, unless it's a nested expression in which case 3 or 4